# Wordpress multi user registration sites

Tags: multisite, users

For one of our customers we are currently creating a (mobile) news app which include the blogs of their WP multisite. We made an REST connection between the DB but are stuck at the following problem:

We like to register people to the WP_user table but we have to give them access to 9 sites in total. Is it possible to dump all users in 1 pool to grant access to post comments on all sites?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

### References

I found several plugins and solutions for this. The most promising seemed to be [MultiUser Management Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management/developers/).

Here's a short and untested rip off from this plugin, as there're easier ways to get the available/registered blogs and normally you won't need their public API functions. Also I think that some stuff they use is already deprecated.

### The Plugin

...is, as I said, untested and should just provide a starting point. You'll have to jump through it, see what works and what doesn't. Then add what you need.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#84066) Register user to all sites upon registration
 */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'WPSE84077_register_everywhere' ) );
class WPSE84077_register_everywhere
{
    protected static $instance;
    public static function init()
    {
        null === self :: $instance AND self :: $instance = new self;
        return self :: $instance;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'wpmu_activate_user', array( $this, 'add_roles' ) );
        add_action( 'wpmu_new_user', array( $this, 'add_roles' ) );
        add_action( 'user_register', array( $this, 'add_roles' ) );
    }
    public function add_roles( $user_id )
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "
            SELECT *
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}blogs
            ORDER BY blog_id
        " );
        if ( empty( $blogs ) )
            return;

        foreach( $blogs as $key => $blog )
        {
            if ( is_user_member_of_blog( $user_id, $blog[ 'blog_id' ] ) )
                continue;

            switch_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );

            // 'none' role means that user registration won't happen on this blog
            $role = get_option( 'default_role', 'none' );
            $role !== 'none' AND add_user_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ], $user_id, $role );

            restore_current_blog();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be nice and give back for receiving help here, you will come back and update my answer with your working solution.